# bc no muestra decimales (bash)

Tags: linux, bash

Os comento un error el cual, intento que me saque la media de una suma de edades, luego divida por la cantidad de veces que esta la entrada, y finalmente haga su respectivo promedio con sus decimales.

El problema reside que cuando quiero que salga los decimales, siempre me sale ".00", aunque si tenga decimales, os enseño el código

```
aja=$(cat .equipos/AJA.txt  | cut -c14-16 | egrep -c "[0-9]{2}")

lineas=1
totalEdad=0
until [ $lineas -gt $aja ];
do
    edad=$(cat .equipos/AJA.txt  | cut -c14-16 | egrep -c "[0-9]{2}" | head -n$lineas | tail -n1)
    totalEdad=$(( $totalEdad + $edad ))
    lineas=$(( $lineas + 1 ))
done

promedio=$(echo "scale=2; $((totalEdad))/$((aja))" | bc)
echo "Edad media del Ajax: $promedio"
```

Como se puede ver uso `linea=1` para la linea del head, `totalEdad` para sacar la suma de todas las edades, ya que esta en un bucle que va aumentando la edad total, haciendo una suma con `$(cat .equipos/AJA.txt  | cut -c14-16 | egrep -c "[0-9]{2}" | head -n$lineas | tail -n1)` que lo que hace, es sacar la edad del listado de jugadores del Ajax en este caso.

Entonces cuando llega el promedio y hace el eco (con ejemplos que he ido viendo por aquí), solo consigo que muestre "24.00" cuando la división deberia ser 587/24 = 24.45, y esto me pasa con los demás equipos.

¿Alguna idea de porque puede ser el error para que no salgan los decimales?, muchas gracias de antemano :)

PD: os dejo el enlace donde me descargo y luego utilizo el archivo, por si os facilita la labor [Plantilla del Ajax](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/4ch6pcussc4w994/AJA.txt)

Comment: Bienvenido. No necesitas editar la pregunta cuando encuentras la solución. Con marcar una respuesta con el tilde es suficiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bc` no es el problema, el problema es que la suma de edades con tu código es 576 y 576 / 24 = 24.00.

El problema está en la linea:

```
cat .equipos/AJA.txt  | cut -c14-16 | egrep -c "[0-9]{2}"
```

donde está usando la opción `-c` de `egrep` que lo que hace es retornar **el número de coincidencias totales**. Eso es 24 (24 números, uno por fila), por lo que 24 * 24 (iteraciones del ciclo) = 576.

cámbiala por:

```
edad=$(cat .equipos/AJA.txt  | cut -c14-16 | grep -E "[0-9]{2}" | head -n$lineas | tail -n1)
```

Ten en cuenta que `egrep` está marcado como obsoleto en favor de `grep -E` **¹**. Considera cambiarlo por tanto.

### Edición

Hay formas de hacer esto mucho más eficiente (como usar `awk` como muestra la [respuesta de Cuauhtil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/617047/15089)). Sin cambiar las herramientas que usas ahora mismo también hay mejoras posibles, por ejemplo, estás aplicando de forma repetitiva `cat | cut | grep` por cada iteración para obtener de nuevo la columna al completo, podrías hacer simplemente:

```
edades=$(cat .equipos/AJA.txt | cut -c14-16 | grep -oE '[0-9]+')
suma=0
n=0
for edad in $edades; do
    suma=$(( suma + edad ))
    n=$(( n + 1 ))
done
promedio=$(echo "scale=2; $suma / $n" | bc)
echo "Edad media del Ajax: $promedio"
```

Otra forma de obtener los valores de la columna es usando el separador. El problema es que en este caso se usan espacios (variables) como separador y debemos "normalizar" la separación entre las columnas antes de poder usar `cut`:

```
edades=$(cat .equipos/AJA.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 |  grep -oE '[0-9]+')
```

o descartar las dos primeras lineas directamente con `tail` y prescindir de `grep`:

```
edades=$(tail -n +3 .equipos/AJA.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

---

1. Con respecto a la obsolescencia  de `egrep`, el propio [manual de Gnu Grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Usage-1) dice (traducción libre):

> 17. ¿Qué pasó con `egrep` y `fgrep`?
>
> La 7ª edición de Unix tenía los comandos `egrep` y `fgrep` que eran
> los homólogos de los modernos `grep -E` y `grep -F`.
>
> Aunque separar `grep` en tres programas era quizás útil para los
> pequeños ordenadores de los años 70, `egrep` y `fgrep` fueron
> considerados obsoletos por POSIX en 1992, eliminados de POSIX en 2001,
> marcados como obsoletos por GNU Grep 2.5.3 en 2007 y modificados para
> emitir advertencias de obsolescencia en GNU Grep 3.8 en 2022.
> Eventualmente se planea eliminarlos por completo.

Comment: Acabo de probarla y también funciona, muchas gracias ^^, esta la comprendo mejor, la curiosidad es que no estaba usando grep porque pensaba que era el contrario, que le egrep sustituyo al grep (o eso me comentaron en clase, lo tengo que debatir con mi profesor) pues empezaré a acostumbrarme a usar el grep en vez de egrep en mis sh ^^ ¡¡muchisimas gracias!! :3

Comment: De hecho, egrep, pgrep, y fgrep, ambas son versiones obsoletas y fueron sustituidas todas por grep con sus respectivos parametros: grep -E, grep -P, grep -F. Eso lo dice la documentacion de grep en su manual

Comment: @KirbyKoNata en el punto 16 y 17 del [apartado "Usage" del manual de GNU Grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Usage-1) tienes una pequeña explicación y algo de historia al respecto de egrep y fgrep si te interesa.

Comment: si, recuerdo que al usar man egrep siempre veo "grep", pues le echaré un ojo a la página, ya la puse en favoritas para ver los ejemplos y su funcionamiento, la verdad que me va a venir muy bien ^^ muchas gracias nuevamente por la ayuda <3

Comment: Me apunto el uso de tr ya que no lo conocia y en el ejemplo se ve realmente bien, ya que era algo que no sabia hacer y lo veo mucho más sencillo :3

Answer (score 2):

`bc` se está comportando bien, pero no estás imprimiendo las cantidades que estás dividiendo y tu problema es que los resultados que tienes en tu archivo no son los que te van a dar el resultado que esperas.

La suma de todas las edades es 590, y la cantidad de personas es 24, asi que 590/24 es 24.58.

Intenta usar awk en su lugar para ser más claro, por ejemplo:

```bash
awk -F " " 'NR>2{sum=sum+$2}
END{
  printf "suma: %i\njugadores: %i\npromedio: %.2f\n", sum, (NR-2), sum/(NR-2)
}' AJA.txt
```

Y obtendrás:

```bash
suma: 590
jugadores: 24
promedio: 24.58
```

Aquí, utilizo NR > 2 para comenzar a leer a partir de la tercera línea.

Trata de no usar demasiadas herramientas de GNU/Linux(cut, egrep, cat, head, bc), cuando hay una que puede hacer todo y de forma más clara y eficiente.

Otra herramienta más sencilla para usar sería *datamash*. La instalas en tu respectiva distribución, y puedes hacer algo como esto:

```bash
$ awk 'NR>2{print $2}' AJA.txt | datamash --round=2 mean 1
24.58
```

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y me ha salido la media leyendo el archivo, muchas gracias ^^ es que comence hace como un mes a programar bash (estoy estudiando el primer año del superior y como estoy un poco avanzado, estoy practicando bash) y conozco las funciones básicas, por lo que no sabia bien como funciona awk, por lo que te agradezco mucho tu explicación, me imagin que -F " " <- esto hace referencia a que los saltos son los espacios, como hacer un cut que conozco yo, y lo otro veo que es una función, esa si tengo que mirarla mas detalladamente para entenderla mejor, ¡¡muchas gracias!! ^^

Comment: acabo de ver lo de datamash, si que lo simplifica :3 pero la idea de el código que uso es poder usarlo en linux sin necesidad de instalar programas alternativos, ya que me gustaria pasarselo a los del foro el cual estoy haciendo este proyecto y lo puedan usar con una MV, emulandolo con Linux o desde su propio sistema, por ello prefiero evitar la instalación de otras, pero si que me lo voy a apuntar y echarle un ojo que se ve bastante sencillo de esa manera para cosas que vaya a usar para mi uso personal ^^